# R convert list of characters and vectors into data.table of characters

Tags: r, list, data.table, data-conversion

I've got a list like the following:

```
    X              Y

   'A'           'B'
    c('G','F')     c('E','D')
```

I need to convert it into a data.table like:

```
 X              Y

'A'           'B'
'G'           'E'
'F'           'D'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

An option would be to do `unnest`

```
library(tidyverse)
df1 %>%
    unnest(X, Y)
```

---

In `base R`, we can do

```
data.frame(lapply(df1, unlist))
```